# NPM package not installing for tpp project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/hzoo/TwitchPlaysX) to get a twitch plays node server up. I installed node.js. I go to the node.js command prompt, CD to the folder containing all the information that I [downloaded](https://github.com/hzoo/TwitchPlaysX/archive/master.zip) from the tutorial, type npm install as said in the tutorial and I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/martynsmith/node-irc.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

error log: [here (Download)](https://mega.nz/file/3rABjaSC#tcEIS8hMWBB3h7koRkXvXmRBJ_WWPAk3JGlpZkL2XpQ)

Comment: Do you have git installed on your system? I think you need that here before doing npm install

Comment: no I dont have it installed, gonna install it now.

Comment: Yes please install it. Do not forget to add it to path environment variables. You are good to go then.

Comment: @vipulw do I just add the git bash exe to the variables? I added C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Git to the variable list

Comment: Is that your install location ? Add your install location of git there. Try doing ```git -v``` in cmd.

Comment: oops I was putting the shorcut instead of the install location in the variables, here are the screen shots: https://mega.nz/folder/m7plEDjQ#p94I3UiZcp1TXWloihi2pA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install gitbash from here - https://gitforwindows.org/
and run npm install in it - see if that works for you.

do cd "~documents/mde/front mission"
and perform npm install

Comment: it tells me "too many arguments" when I try to cd to the folder in git bash

Comment: can you please share screenshot. Also just install git and add it to env. var. in your system.

Comment: I think your path has folders with spaces on them, try adding double quotes to your path 

example :

cd "c:\temp dir\temp dir2\your web app"

Comment: do cd "~documents/mde/front mission"
and perform npm install

Comment: ok, so it installed the package I think, with npm install. but now when I run "npm start" it gives me this error: https://mega.nz/file/HugA2KhK#GnWttQnIFi1frEcVSdsdgB94t2J6X-lFSEDjdCtG1Pg

Comment: as per the log that you shared just now - it's not a problem with the npm now, your TwitchPlaysX@0.0.1 startup script is wrong.

Comment: it also gave me these errors when I "npm install" [link](https://mega.nz/file/bvwlgBSa#Fnc49gaADy7XLhDi4WJbE41Tj9pWgQF5B2useBwjdLk)

Comment: can I put multiple questions as the right answer? because I didnt know about git either and that helped

Comment: You can accept one and vote for the other answers as mentioned here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90525/mark-multiple-answers-as-correct

Comment: once one issue is solved, do I make another thread for the next issue?

Comment: Yes - keep the issues as granular as possible, it will help you get your issues answered quickly. you can create another thread for the "npm start" issue that you mentioned.